# How can I style a div tag to look like a product catalog on a mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I am working on a site that will have a mobile catalog. I want it to look like the ones companies like Best Buy and Target have(see below image). I assume they use a div, but I am not sure. 
[image: What I am aiming for. The way the products are listed.]

Comment: you can use div's or list's for this ... why not look at the source code for the html page to see exactly what they did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the documentation of jquery mobile     [ListView](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/)

listview code

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img1.jpg">
            <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
            <p>Broken Bells</p></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img2.jpg">
            <h2>Warning</h2>
            <p>Hot Chip</p></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">
            <img src="img3.jpg">
            <h2>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>
            <p>Phoenix</p></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```